# Titanium webservice response timeout control

Tags: android, timeout, titanium-mobile, webservice-client

I'm using Titanium for an Android device and SOAP for the webservice data transmission. I am able to abort the process if the connection fails, but I need to abort the process if the webservice takes longer than 10 seconds to response, due, for example, to a slow internet transmission. How can I control that if the process was already started? I assume I could control it on the device side (Titanium), but I can look outside the box and maybe do something on the webservice side instead. I appreciate your time..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using **setTimeout** function of HttpClient refere this link
[HttpClient Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-setTimeout).